# Catching exceptions in Kotlin Flows with .catch

Tags: android, exception, kotlin-flow

I'm a bit confused on how catching exceptions exactly work in Kotlin flows.

Looking at this sample code from https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#exceptions.

```
class NewsRepository(...) {
val favoriteLatestNews: Flow<List<ArticleHeadline>> =
    newsRemoteDataSource.latestNews
        .map { news -> news.filter { userData.isFavoriteTopic(it) } }
        .onEach { news -> saveInCache(news) }
        // If an error happens, emit the last cached values
        .catch { exception -> emit(lastCachedNews()) }
```

Does `.catch` catch any exceptions thrown by the following?

1. `newsRemoteDataSource.latestNews`
2. `.map`
3. `.onEach`

If an exception was caught from `.map` for example, does `.onEach` ever get run? Or does it jump straight to the `.catch`?

Answer (score 0):

> Does .catch catch any exceptions thrown by the following?
>
> 1. newsRemoteDataSource.latestNews
> 2. map
> 3. onEach

`catch` catches `exception` thrown from any of these, and it would cancel the `flow` as soon as it catches any `exception`.

> If an exception was caught from .map for example, does .onEach ever get run? Or does it jump straight to the .catch?

Order of execution is from left to right, so in this case, if an exception occurs in `map` it would instantly catch the `exception` and cancel the flow, and it won't run `onEach`.  If you move `onEach` before `map`, it would do the vice versa.

If any `exception` occurs in `newsRemoteDataSource.latestNews`, it won't run either of `map` and `onEach`.